# Localizing HTML submit button label in Wicket

Tags: html, wicket

How do I put a localized message on the face of a submit button? I am using Wicket, and normally to use a localized message, I'd use something like `<wicket:message key="message-key"/>`

I have an HTML button defined as `<input type="submit" value="login"/>`

I want to localize/internationalize the value 'login'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/General+i18n+in+Wicket:

If you want to use Wicket's i18n in other HTML elements, for example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

You can't use the `<wicket:message/>` component, you should use the following:

```
<input type="submit" wicket:message="value:page.search"/>
```

Comment: Page not found on URL you requested.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using `wicket:message="value:yourPropertyName"` would be to set a [ResourceModel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/ResourceModel.html) with the button in your Java code. It has the same effect.

```
Button b = new Button("wicketButtonName", new ResourceModel("yourPropertyName"));
```